numpy : f-ordered arrays have slower assignment than their transpose
If I have an array: x = np.array(np.random.rand(2000, 400), order='F'), and create a mask: y = (x > .5) (which also happens to become F-contiguous), then the following code:
x[y] = np.nan
Is significantly slower than: (with twice the time taken)
x.T[y.T] = np.nan
However, on benchmarking on my local machine with Py 3.10.12 with NumPy 1.21.5, there is still a performance gain, but lesser (~18%) (please see EDIT)
The platform of the server is linux x64, python 3.6.15, numpy 1.17.3.
It would help to know when the change was introduced*, but I'm having trouble pin-pointing exactly what changed between the two numpy versions - could you please help me in finding what could be the cause, and where I can inspect it in the source?
*so we can optimize similar operations, in case upgrading introduces incompatibility
P.S. it's a bit silly to post a question by getting so far, but I could find no other information easily regarding this fundamental change. I haven't gone through the changelogs yet.
EDIT: corrected versions. Also, it seems that there is a speed-up on my local machine as well, sorry for missing this earlier.
Timing code:
import numpy as np

source = np.asfortranarray(np.random.rand(5000, 300))
source[3000][150] = np.nan
y = (source > .5)
y[0][0] = not y[0][0]

def trial1():
    global source, y
    x = np.array(source, order='F', copy=True)
    x[y] = np.nan

def trial2():
    global source, y
    x = np.array(source, order='F', copy=True)
    x.T[y.T] = np.nan

print (f"x flags : {source.flags}")
print (f"y flags : {y.flags}")

import timeit
for i in range(5):
    print(f"Without transpose: {timeit.timeit(trial1, number=100)}")
    print(f"With transpose: {timeit.timeit(trial2, number=100)}")

Locally: x, y are f-contiguous; without transpose ~0.66s, with transpose: ~0.53s
Server: x, y are f-contiguous; without transpose ~2.45s, with transpose: ~1.35s
EDIT #2: After @hpaulj 's comment, here are some perf stats:

With transpose (server)

        54,448,864      cache-references:u                                                 
        11,400,924      cache-misses:u                   #   20.939 % of all cache refs    
    18,837,142,074      instructions:u                                                     
            14,265      faults:u


Without transpose (server)

       168,729,841      cache-references:u                                                 
       105,950,111      cache-misses:u                   #   62.793 % of all cache refs    
    17,314,722,307      instructions:u                                                     
            17,824      faults:u


With transpose (local - i7-13700)

      231,283,068      cpu_core/cache-references/                                              (94.47%)
         4,298,631      cpu_atom/cache-references/                                              (27.28%)
        58,979,974      cpu_core/cache-misses/           #   25.50% of all cache refs           (94.47%)
         2,696,648      cpu_atom/cache-misses/           #    1.17% of all cache refs           (27.28%)
    36,328,986,080      cpu_core/instructions/                                                  (94.47%)
    30,357,732,295      cpu_atom/instructions/                                                  (27.28%)
             6,208      faults


Without transpose (local)

       229,462,046      cpu_core/cache-references/                                              (95.34%)
           786,111      cpu_atom/cache-references/                                              (22.32%)
       107,393,341      cpu_core/cache-misses/           #   46.80% of all cache refs           (95.34%)
           467,948      cpu_atom/cache-misses/           #    0.20% of all cache refs           (22.32%)
    34,146,964,025      cpu_core/instructions/                                                  (95.34%)
    37,761,817,540      cpu_atom/instructions/                                                  (22.32%)
             6,214      faults                                                              

I think, the cache misses indicate that there is a difference in accessing these arrays (it could be the indexing expression, or the array itself). However, the cache references differ greatly on the server - this could be due to the hardware and the cause of the larger performance difference.
NOTE: I have also tried the above tests on Py 3.12.3 with NumPy 1.26.4 (linux x64 with i7-1360P) and the results are close to the "local" machine above
EDIT#3: Seems entirely due to hardware - running with Py 3.6.15 and NumPy 1.17.3 gives the same performance ratio and perf stats as the new ones.

is it possible to just update the target system to more recent versions? it seems reasonable that in the intervening 5-ish years some improvements have arrived, so you're either stuck or find some regression .. otherwise you'll use whatever the most recent version you have available

It's the ideal solution but I think also difficult (a lot of numpy based code has been written). Still, I'm curious about the internals here

mm .. you may be best off comparing straces to see what it gets up to, though the NumPy changelogs are of excellent quality (and you'll likely need to visit them, I know there may be some deprecations like methods forcing list/array instead of generators) .. plausibly you're finding something strange like the array from .rand() has a different dtype or is a view until operated on, though I doubt it .. someone may give you a good Answer if you provide more solid debugging details and experiments, at least 1) how are you doing timing? 2) what happens if you change a value intermediately?

Release notes and change logs focus on things that the end users need to know.  If this is produced by changes in numpy code, it would be deep, out of sight of users.  Your arrays are also large enough that memory management - paging and caching, etc, could be a factor.  The server may be old enough, and small enough memory per users, that these memory issues are significant.

@ti7 I've edited and added the timing code with your suggestions

@hpaulj You're right, I missed when testing yesterday, that there is a speed difference on the local machine with newer libs too. It seems this could be due to hardware. I've attached some perf stats. Now I'm curious about why there are lesser references in the server; this could be a missing optimization in the older libraries perhaps. I'll try with the older package on a new machine.
